# Retrieve specific table fields in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i have a table in which i want to get only two  columns data .. right now i am using findAll method ... i don't know how can I get the specific two fields data in CakePHP

```
  $recentContacts = $this->Contact->find('all',
        array(
            'order'=>'Contact.idContacts DESC',
            'limit' => 6,
            'conditions' => array(
             'Contact.User_id' => $id)));
```

in my contacts table there are two fields one is **"name"** and other is **"number"**
which I want to extract ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding `fields` attribute.

```
$recentContacts = $this->Contact->find('all',
array
(
    'order'=> array( 'Contact.id' , 'Contacts DESC'),
    'limit' => 6,
    'fields' => array(
        'Contact.name',
        'Contact.number'
    ),
    'conditions' => array
    (
        'Contact.User_id' => $id
    )
));
```

Comment: @dipeshparmer well when i paste your query it is giving me a brackets errors .. i think you are missing something

Comment: @hellosheikh now copy paste code it will work i forget to add `,` after fields array

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this way with your same code to add fields

```
 $recentContacts = $this->Contact->find('all',
        array(
            'order'=>'Contact.idContacts DESC',
            'limit' => 6,
            'fields' => array(
                 'Contact.name',
                 'Contact.number'
             ),
            'conditions' => array(
             'Contact.User_id' => $id)));
```

in previous answer they have changed you id instead of idContacts, you can just copy my code and solve your problem.

let me know if i can help you more.